# load_opus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, opus

I'm developing a discord bot, and I tried to implement music streaming, then this problem appeared. First I needed to install `ffmpeg` in my virtual environment. When installed, a new error appeared `opus is not loaded`, so apparently I had to add `discord.opus.load_opus()` in my code (somewhere before all things related to audio), but then this error came in,

`File "/Users/rafael/PycharmProjects/Discord/main.py", line 65, in <module> discord.opus.load_opus() TypeError: load_opus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Did some research and came up with some things which I tried:

`->brew install opus` (in my virtual environment) then run the code again but The same error appeared

`->pip install opuslib` (in the v.e too) error appeared as well

->adding some of the file routes which I found in the opus folder with not much idea of which one I was meant to supply in the "name" argument but several `image not found` errors occur

I read that this `discord.opus.load_opus()` line should work without arguments.

I'm using macOS, and I'm not hosting at any server. I don't know what am I doing wrong, and haven't found much useful information by myself. If I see this problem goes on, I will try to host this bot in Heroku which I've seen that using a patch this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Look doc, you need provide name argument.

```
discord.opus.load_opus(name)
```

[discord.opus.load_opus](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=load_opus#discord.opus.load_opus)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already tried using ctypes.util.find_library() so that i can find opus library but this returns None, and as I said, already tried providing 'name' argument which is related to the path where I have opus installed, and didn't worked